# Expand Regular Expression snippet to allow longer TLDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am working with an open source application from Foradian and while trying to add administrative users, I get an error stating that the e-mail address is invalid. I have gone through the source code and found a regex snippet that performs this check, or so I think.

`/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i`

How can I make the application accept the newer and longer TLDs such as .university, .museum, and others by altering the snippet above?

Comment: You can just remove the `4` from last check and it will just check if the ending domain have atleast 2 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the 4 from last check and it will just check if the ending domain have at least 2 characters.

```
 /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,}$/i
```

[Here is working example.](http://www.regexr.com/3ae5m)

Comment: Thank you, Coder of Code. I'll mark as an accepted solution shortly. I can't do it right now, the system through up an error saying I should try in 8 minutes.

Comment: Why at least 2 characters? I think `a@b` is a perfectly valid address.

Comment: I just tried to explain and write to the answer what OP needed.

Comment: Email validation is a sore point for me, since my address, which is both theoretically legal according to the specs and pragmatically working in the sense that I can send and receive mails without problems, gets rejected by about 1 in 10 websites with bad validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution not long after posting the question:

`^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|university)$`

The above allows me specify which TLDs are accepted.

For now, I've opted for the accepted solution marked above as that saves me the trouble of editing the source when newer TLDs are added.